# Lisp Assign variable to parameter

Tags: lisp

I am attempting to assign the variable a the parameter (list) in my function. I keep getting variable L has no value, how can I assign the variable inside the function the list parameter?

```
   (defun pali(list)
    (defvar a nil)
    (defvar b nil)
    (setq a (list))
    (setq b (reverse list))
    )
```

Comment: What are you passing in to it? This seems to compile when I try. This issue might be with what you are giving it

Comment: You need to specify the precise form you evaluate and copy/paste the error message.

Comment: in `(setq a (list))` you first evaluate `list` (run a function `(list)`) and then assign returned value to `a`. is it by design?

Comment: `defvar` is a top-level operator and has no place inside a `defun`. Use `let` instead.

Comment: `list` is your argument `(list)` calls the function `list` with no argument and thus return `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is

```
(defun pali (list)
   (let ((a list))
        ((b (reverse list)))
     ...))
```

It's almost certainly wrong to put DEFVAR inside a function, and likely to hurt you badly if you use DEFVAR with names like A and B. DEFVAR makes a global variable, and it makes the symbol that names it "special"; everywhere you use it in future, you'll be getting the symbol-value instead of a lexical variable. Strange things will happen when you're not expecting it. That's why DEFVAR variables are usually named like *A*, etc., instead of just A. Use LET to make a normal lexical variable. And then there's not a lot of point setting it to NIL initially and then using SETQ to alter it, though you can do that if you like. Even just

```
(let (a b)
   (setq a list
         b (reverse list))
   ...)
```

if that's what you want [Note you can use a single SETQ to set many variables. Don't have to, of course]